# Spring Data Rest HATEOAS configure a sub-URI

Tags: rest, spring-data, spring-hateoas

I have Spring Data Rest with Spring Hateoas configured, specifically Spring-Data-Mongo.
Works like a charm.

Trouble is, entities are at the root of the URI.
For example, for entity Person, and assume my servlet context is abc, it would be `http://localhost:8080/abc/person`

I would like to have a "sub-URI" to handle these entities.
For example, `http://localhost:8080/abc/rest/person` or `http://localhost:8080/abc/api/person`

I've looked at documentation, manuals, tutorials, and searched the internet.
I can't seem to find a solution.

Does somebody know how to do this?

Also, a couple more scenarios:
1. Is it possible to have multiple URI for an entity?  For example, .../person and .../people point to the same entity.
2. If I wanted to use the same URI for an entity, what is best practices for one client having access to certain methods, while another client has different access.  For example, one client can only read, and another can read/write.

Finally, is there a library out there that implement Spring Security with API Keys?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

to put all rest api's under a sub path use the RepositoryRestMvcConfigurator

```
package se.digiplant.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;

import java.net.URI;

@Configuration
public class RestMvcConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    private static final URI BASE_URI = URI.create("/api");

    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
        config.setBaseUri(BASE_URI);
    }
}
```